# Mapping row items to fixed columns set of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to map `time` wise each `channel`'s `velocity` and `note` to another data frame.

For example:
I have a table in this format:

[image]

It is not visible in this table but for each `time` multiple `channel` like (1, 2, ... 16) may be available (each channel occurs only once for each `time` i.e. `channel` do no repeat for a particular `time`) and their corresponding `note` and `velocity` values.

As channels are in a fixed range from `1 to 16` only.
So, this leads to the creation of `32` fixed columns of a new data frame like:

`| time | C1 note| C1 velocity| C2 note| C2 velocity| ...... | C16 note| C16 velocity|`

If a value is not found for a particular column fill it with `0`.

Is there a way to do this in a pandish way?

Comment: Use unstack(), to move channel in column headers creating a multiindex column header, then you can flatten your column headers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
timelist = np.arange(1,21)
channels = [1,2,3,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'notes':np.random.randint(100,200,80), 
                   'velocity':np.random.randint(1000,9000, 80)},
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timelist, channels]))

df = df.rename_axis(['Time', 'Channel'])
```

Input dataframe:

```
              notes  velocity
Time Channel                 
1    1          199      7683
     2          106      5981
     3          111      8324
     5          177      6123
2    1          113      6608
...             ...       ...
19   5          120      1779
20   1          149      7591
     2          171      8513
     3          128      1341
     5          192      5942

[80 rows x 2 columns]
```

Try unstacking and flattening headers:

```
df_out = df.unstack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['notes','velocity'], 
                                                          [1,2,3,4,5]]), 
                              axis=1, 
                              fill_value=0)

df_out.columns = [f'C{j} {i}' for i,j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Output:

```
      C1 notes  C2 notes  C3 notes  C4 notes  C5 notes  C1 velocity  C2 velocity  C3 velocity  C4 velocity  C5 velocity
Time                                                                                                                   
1          199       106       111         0       177         7683         5981         8324            0         6123
2          113       115       151         0       115         6608         3461         8315            0         1142
3          142       160       160         0       130         4394         7909         1738            0         1283
4          128       175       148         0       197         4002         4245         7066            0         1851
5          148       129       196         0       144         7755         3266         4123            0         6621
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing this concept to me and for a quick and witty reply.